# repeat image in iOs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, gradient

I have an image which is 1*90 with gradient and i want to use it as background for different height say for example for first  row of height 90 then no issues but second one is 100 then third is of 80... hw do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

try `+ [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`

Comment: it works for simple image but not for gradient. because repeating image will start repeating itself  again from top once its reaches height above its own height  so looses the gradient

Answer (score 3):

```
self.someImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)];
```

that will resize image and keep 10 pixels at top, 0 at left, 10 at bottom and 0 at right. You can also try

```
self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]] autorelease];
self.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Hope it helps