# Set UIImageView with size 10x10 as background for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have image with size 10x10 px and I need to set the image as background for UIView with the image copied horizontally and vertical, not stretched. Is it possible to do with ios?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533721/repeat-image-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bodyBG"]];
```

It copied horizontally and vertical in default.